# Can using the BULK API to perform SOQL queries save on total number of queries?

Tags: rest, limits

This is a pretty hypothetical question. So I apologize if this isn't sufficient information.

Let's say I want to query for about 50000 accounts. And I have a very simple select statement that tries to query all accounts.

```
select Id, Name from Account
```

Is there any advantage between using the BULK API to run this query versus the standard REST API.

My understanding is the standard REST API allows you to query 2000 records before you need to make another query. However, the limits on the BULK API seem more vague.

I understand this is a vague question. But we are trying to cut down on the total number of API queries and are trying to decide if using BULK could somehow help us lower our total number of API calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't save on the number of queries. The main point of the Bulk API for queries is it saves on the number of round-trips that you need, since the result is delivered as a single file at the end of the query result; this can save the number of API calls you need to use as a result. Normally, you're limited to 2,000 rows per API call, so 50,000 rows, for example, would be 25 API calls, but using the Bulk API and a reasonable time wait, you can get those same 50,000 rows in just 3-4 API calls instead.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying even though I technically make less "API" calls, each 2000 rows still counts as an API call for Salesforce limits

Comment: @Cameron No, you make *actual* fewer API calls. With the SOAP API, you'd be using 1 API call per up to 2000 records, while with the Bulk API, you can get up to 50,000 records for two API calls (one to start the query, one to get the results), but since polling is needed, there might be more API calls involved (but far less than the 25 minimum you'd use with SOAP).